# Reading a label from input file that can be in a random order and assigning to variables

Tags: c++, string, label, fstream

I am trying to create a program that will read a user given input file and assign values to some variables in the code for a school project.
Here are a couple input file examples:

```
a 3
b 4
c 5
? equilateral
```

```
? equilateral
a 8
c 6
b 8
```

These input files can have the four items in any order, but I can't figure out how to read the label in the input file and assign it to my variables that I've assigned. I have to use an if-then-else-if to decide which label needs to be read, and the code should be able to be copied 3 times so that there is no modification needed to read every label and assign the variables.

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <cmath>
#include <iomanip>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
  string filename, guess;
  double a, b, c;

  cout << "Opening input file: " << filename;
  cin << filename;
  fstream InFile;
  InFile.open(filename.c_str());
  if(InFile.fail()) 
  { 
    cout << string(15,'*') << " File Open Error " << string(15,'*') << endl; 
    cout << "==> Input file failed to open properly!!\n"; 
    cout << "==> Attempted to open file: " << filename << endl; 
    cout << "==> Terminating program!!!\n"; 
    cout << string(47,'*') << endl << endl; 
     return 1; 
  }  
  
  if()
  {
    
  }
  else if()
  {
    
  }
  else if()
  { 
    
  }
  else
  {
    
  }

  cout << "\nReading Values From Input File..." << endl;
  cout << "Summary of Data Read..." << endl;
  cout << "Side A = " << a << endl;
  cout << "Side B = " << b << endl;
  cout << "Side C = " << c << endl;
  cout << "Guess  = " << guess << endl;
  
  InFile.close();
  return 0;
}
```

Any Help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Are `a`, `b`, `c`, `?`,  the only valid _keys_ in that mapping?

Comment: You can use the stream extraction operator `>>` to read the first character of the line, and then compare that character in your `if`...`else if` statements with the characters `'a'`, `'b'`, `'c'` and `'?'`. The stream extraction operator can be used with different data types, including `std::string`, `double` and `int`. That way, the content of all `if`...`else if` blocks can be identical, except for the variable name.

Answer (score 0):

I'll assume `equilateral` is the only valid type (thus there can only be 3 sides), also that the user input is always valid (eg.: No side is missing, etc)
With this the solution becomes pretty simple:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

int main() {
    std::ifstream InFile("input.txt");

    // Assume there are no trailing new-lines, and what not

    double a, b, c;
    do {
        char chr;
        InFile.read(&chr, 1); // Read first char on line

        // If we were doing error checking here it should be checked if `InFile.valid()` (Otherwise `chr` won't have a valid value)
        std::cout << "Read:" << c << '\n';
        switch (chr) {
        case '?':
            break; // Ignore this, nothing to do
        case 'a': 
            InFile >> a;
            break;
        case 'b': 
            InFile >> b;
            break;
        case 'c': 
            InFile >> c;
            std::cout << "case c: " << c << '\n';
            break;
        default:
            break; // If this point is reached something was invalid
        }

        InFile.ignore(10000, '\n'); // Ignore up to next new line charcter
    } while (InFile.good());

    std::cout 
        << "a = " << a 
        << "; b = " << b;
        << "; c = " << c;
        
}
```

There's quite a lot of error checking it's missing, but that's fine, its supposed to show how it can be done.